# result_of, make_tuple, parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I would like to obtain the type returned by `std::make_tuple` for a given parameter pack. Up to now I have written the following code:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>

template <class T>
struct unwrap_refwrapper
{
    using type = T;
};

template <class T>
struct unwrap_refwrapper<std::reference_wrapper<T>>
{
    using type = T&;
};

template <class T>
using special_decay_t = typename unwrap_refwrapper<typename std::decay<T>::type>::type;

template<class ... Types>
struct foo
{
    typedef std::tuple<special_decay_t<Types>...> tuple_t;
};

int main()
{
    short s;
    // t should be std::tuple<int, double&, short&>
    typedef foo<int, double&, decltype(std::ref(s))>::tuple_t t;
}
```

But I find it quite ugly to copy part of the [possible implementation of `std::make_tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple), which I did here.

I would like to achieve the given effect using `std::result_of` or something of that kind.

My attempt looks as follows:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>

template<class ... Types>
struct foo
{
    typedef typename std::result_of<
        std::make_tuple(Types...)>::type tuple_t;
};

int main()
{
    short s;
    // t should be std::tuple<int, double&, short&>
    typedef foo<int, double&, decltype(std::ref(s))>::tuple_t t;
}
```

but it does [not compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2de192df56ac7ada).

How can it be done?

Comment: You should give `result_of` a callable object, but you are actually giving it the result of calling the function. You could use `decltype` in its place.

Comment: Why do you need complex logic to reverse-engineer the return type of `make_tuple`? It's specified, and it's not super complex.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I try to avoid reverse-engineering the return type of `make_tuple` and did not succeed so far. But [T.C.s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42001013/result-of-make-tuple-parameter-pack/42001110#42001110) is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Yes, true, the solution is really quite nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<class... Ts>
struct foo
{
    using tuple_t = decltype(std::make_tuple(std::declval<Ts>()...));
};
```